# Limits & Derivatives - Derivative of a function

Tags: limits, derivatives

We are learning "derivative of a function" under the chapter of "Limits and Derivatives".

The following is the definition we have in our book

[image]

I have the following example in my book.  I'd like to know what it means and **how it can be used for practical purposes**.

[image]

From the above problem, if I substitute $x=2$ in $f(x)=3x$ - I'd normally expect $6$ but here it is $3$. How does it really work?

Comment: Applications of the derivative has been asked countless times before...  I would recommend a quick Google search,  or even just search this site.  Name pretty much any higher math,  engineering,  or science discipline and the derivative will come into play.  Examples include harmonic motion,  wave analysis,  structural analysis,  and even Neural Networks (a type of AI,  and one of my favorite examples!!)

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is asking about application. I think they're asking for clarification in finding a numerical derivative.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen, I totally agree. I should have googled it first. Thanks for your examples.

Answer (score 2):

Substituting $x=2$ into $f(x)=3x$ does give you $f(2)=6$. But this is the value of the function at $x=2$, and not the value of the derivative!

In fact, the derivative of $f(x)=3x$ is $f'(x)=3$. You can prove this via the limit definition. Substituting $x=2$ into $f'(x)=3$ does give $f'(2)=3$, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

See f(x) and f'(x) are two different things,do not expect f(a) and f'(a) to give same value. When you find f'(a) you are actually finding the slope of the tangent to f(x) at x=a. It has no relation whatsoever with f(a).

Comment: `you are actually finding the slope of the tangent to f(x) at x=a` can you please explain little more on this? or provide me some reference where I can understand this better. Please cite practical applications of this (if any)

Comment: You can find the equation of the tangent to any curve, (circle,parabola,ellipse e.t.c), if you know the point at which you want to draw it. by finding f'(x) at that point, you will have the tangent's slope, and so, the tangent equation will become $$y-y_o=f'(x_o).(x-x_o)$$ where $(x_o,y_o)$ is the point at which you chose to draw your tangent.